# Why does the compiler create a variable that's only used once?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following two examples, both compiled with `g++ (GCC) 12.1.0` targetting `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`: `g++ -O3 -std=gnu++20 main.cpp`.

Example 1:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(){ std::cout << "Foo constructor" << std::endl;}
    Foo(Foo&& f) { std::cout << "Foo move constructor" << std::endl;}
    Foo(const Foo& f) {std::cout << "Foo copy constructor" << std::endl;}

    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo destructor" << std::endl;}
};

class Baz {
private:
    Foo foo;
public:
    Baz(Foo foo) : foo(std::move(foo)) {}
    ~Baz() { std::cout << "Baz destructor" << std::endl;}
};

Foo bar() {
    return Foo();
}

int main() {
    Baz baz(bar());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Foo constructor
Foo move constructor
Foo destructor
Baz destructor
Foo destructor
```

Example 2:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(){ std::cout << "Foo constructor" << std::endl;}
    Foo(Foo&& f) { std::cout << "Foo move constructor" << std::endl;}
    Foo(const Foo& f) {std::cout << "Foo copy constructor" << std::endl;}

    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo destructor" << std::endl;}
};

class Baz {
private:
    Foo foo;
public:
    Baz(Foo foo) : foo(std::move(foo)) {}
    ~Baz() { std::cout << "Baz destructor" << std::endl;}
};

Foo bar() {
    return Foo();
}

int main() {
    // DIFFERENCE IS RIGHT HERE
    Foo f = bar();
    Baz baz(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Foo constructor
Foo copy constructor
Foo move constructor
Foo destructor
Baz destructor
Foo destructor
Foo destructor
```

So the difference here is that there is an additional instance of `Foo`, which needs to be handled. I find this difference quite shocking, as my (apparently untrained) eyes would not even consider these pieces of code effectively different. Moreover, a collegue might ask me to turn example 1 into example 2 for readability and suddenly I will be incurring a performance penalty!

So why are example 1 and 2 so different according to the compiler/C++ spec that the resulting code suddenly needs to copy? Why can the compiler not generate the same code for both cases?

Comment: @273K I was really struggling with a title here, what would be a better title?

Comment: "The compiler can clearly see that ..." - unless you are intimately familiar with GCC internals, that seems like quite a bold claim.

Comment: @infinitezero `g++ -O3 -std=gnu++20 main.cpp`, also added in question.

Comment: You can get rid of the copy constructor by explicitly calling `std::move`, [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq39MKhar)

Comment: @infinitezero I know, but that does not resolve my question. I understand that two moves is better than a move and a copy, but a single move is better still. Therefore my question: why cant the compiler generate a single move in both cases?

Comment: yeah, I mean, the difference is that when you assign `bar()` to f, it becomes a named value, not an r-value so you need to explicitely move it. Remember moving is destructive. C++ can't auto-move a named value because you might use `f` elsewhere and expect it to be a valid value not whatever was left after a move.

Comment: @jwezorek Looking at specifically this case, it seems clear to me that it is impossible that `f` will ever be used again: It does not leave the scope of `main` and it not used after constructing `Baz`. So to me it seems like an easy optimization that is missed. But I do not actually think it is missed by the compiler, I think I misunderstood something else.

Comment: @Cheiron I agree that it's not obvious why `f` isn't moved if it apparently never is used again, but things are complicated. The destructor of `f` will run at the end of `main` anyway and the compiler doesn't know whether you do or don't want side effects from that and how that relates to passing `f`to the `Baz` constructor. If you really want different semantics (move-by-default, moved-from values don't need destroying), consider learning Rust ;-)

Comment: `Foo& operator=(const Foo&& f)` that's an odd parameter for being `const` for a **move** assignment operator.

Comment: Yeah, according to the downvotes its a bad question in general. I removed the assigments as they did not do anything for the example anyway.

Comment: Sean parent made a tweet about this very thing years ago. https://twitter.com/SeanParent/status/1341924869039001600

Comment: The title seems to be increasingly mismatched to the question. There continues to be no forwarding, and now there's also no assignment. Maybe something like "Why doesn't the compiler elide creation of a variable that's only used once"?

Comment: @NathanPierson Sure

Comment: Did you copy/paste the output or write from memory? The move constructor must execute before copy constructor. Your output looks incorrect.

Comment: I did copy paste. The copy happens on constructor call, the move happens in the constructor, so the order seems correct to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
Foo f = bar();
Baz baz(f);
return 0
```

It is indeed obvious that `f` will never be used again and the compiler probably even works this out. However the compiler isn't *allowed* to move `f` into `baz`, all optimisations done by the compiler must result in your program having the same behaviour (if the program is well defined to start with). Especially in your case where the move and copy constructors print different things, making this optimisation would change the behaviour of your program. In a more realistic program the compiler may be able to deduce that the code would have the same behaviour with a move or a copy and change a copy into a move but it's always best to give the compiler as much help as possible and not rely on it making optimisations.

If you know that you don't need `f` any more then you can tell the compiler this by converting it to an rvalue reference using `std::move`, then it will use the move constructor (if available):

```
Foo f = bar();
Baz baz(std::move(f));
return 0
```

Comment: This is the best answer, that being said, It would be nice if someone created a proposal so that C++ compilers could perform this optimization.

Comment: @Taekahn nobody is likely to make a proposal for optimising this, the behaviour of your program changing depending on whether a variable is used multiple times or not would be very surprising. C++ is a language where you have to be explicit about a lot of things, if you don't want to use a variable any more give it to someone else by using `std::move` otherwise the compiler *has* to assume you want to keep it

Comment: Couldn't that same logic be said, more or less, about copy elision?

Comment: no, copy elision only happens to temporaries, where its not possible to use the objects again anyway

Comment: @Taekahn: Imagine a world where this was allowed. What if `f` holds open a global resource (e.g. a DB transaction committed on destruction)? What if said resource maintains global/threadlocal state? You can execute other DB commands and they are implicitly part of the same transaction, and you have one more such operation after creating `baz` (maybe `baz` is in a subscope, so it and the `Foo` it holds get destroyed before the operation). Now if `f` gets implicitly moved/copy-elided away, there is *no* `Foo` for that final line; what used to be part of an atomic transaction is now unrelated.

Comment: @Taekahn: Note that Rust (being newer and not constrained by design decisions made in the '80s) can do what you suggest (I don't know if it *does*, but the design would allow it). It works because Rust uses move semantics by default, so when you pass the argument in by value, the source becomes invalid. Whether that's done by move-semantics (construct locally, move to called function's arguments) or by elision doesn't change behavior (so long as in the elision case, it ensures the object exists at the line of construction, e.g. preallocating the space used for the arguments).

Comment: @ShadowRanger something I wouldn’t discussing at length but the comment aren’t really the forum. I will make one clarification though. My intent was that it will implicitly move _at last usage_ , not every usage like rust. Since there is only one usage in the example I didn’t spell it out, but I should have been more clear perhaps.

Comment: @Taekahn: Yeah, and the problem is it's impossible to truly define "last usage" in any language that isn't purely functional and doesn't have move semantics baked in. I know you only want "move on last use", but C++ can't define "last use" any better than "when it leaves scope" (or closely related, when it is moved-from) thanks to the possibility of arbitrary side-effects. I mention Rust because it's one of two language designs that would allow this, but as long as C++ guarantees specific orders of initialization and destruction tied to block scopes, with possible side-effects, it can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

> why are example 1 and 2 so different according to the compiler/C++ spec that the resulting code suddenly needs to copy?

Because in example 2 you have a variable named `f` of type `Foo` which is used to initialize `baz` while in example 1 you're initializing `baz` with a *prvalue* of type `Foo` which will result in directly constructing the parameter `foo` and then moving from it.

To be more precise, in example 2 since `f` in the statement `Baz baz(f);` is an *lvalue expression* and so the copy ctor `Foo::Foo(const Foo&)` will be used to initialize the parameter `Foo foo` of the converting ctor `Baz::Baz(Foo)`. Thus we get the output corresponding to the copy ctor. Next due to `foo(std::move(foo))` we will also get a call to the move ctor.

While in example 1, `bar()` is a prvalue of type `Foo`. This means that the parameter `Foo foo` of `Baz::Baz(Foo)` will be directly constructed(due to mandatory copy elison in C++17) and then due to `foo(std::move(foo))` we also get a call to the move ctor.

---

Let's see step by step explanation.

##### Case 1

Here we consider example:

```
Baz baz(bar());
```

**Step 1**: The parameterized ctor `Baz::Baz(Foo foo)` will be used here.

**Step 2**: Since `bar()` is a prvalue, the parameter named `foo` of the parameterized ctor `Baz::Baz(Foo foo)` will be directly constructed due to mandatory copy elison in C++17. Thus we get the first statement of the output `Foo constructor`.

**Step 3** Now due to `foo(std::move(foo))` we get the call to the move ctor `Foo::Foo(Foo&& f)` and so the second statement of the output `Foo move constructor`.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider:

```
Foo f = bar();  //this will call the default ctor and so we get the first statement of the output
//------v------->f is an lvalue
Baz baz(f);
```

**Step 1** Here also the parameterized ctor `Baz::Baz(Foo foo)` will be used.

**Step 2** But this time since `f` is an lvalue expression the copy ctor `Foo::Foo(const Foo&)` will be used to initialized the parameter named `foo` of the parameterized ctor `Baz::Baz(Foo foo)`. Thus we get the second statement of the output `Foo copy constructor`.

**Step 3** Next due to `foo(std::move(foo))` we get a call to the move ctor and the third statement of the output `Foo move constructor`